# How to run tests with cookies/authentication in GitHub Actions?

Tags: cookies, https, next.js, cypress, github-actions

I’m using Cypress to test a Next.js app. (I’m actually using Blitz.js, which configures a lot of things for me)

It sets a lot of Cookies and Local Storage to securely figure out authentication. However, it does not persist over http because it needs to be secure.

I’ve written tests that work on a proxy server with https and a domain name, but I can’t figure out how to get something similar to work with GitHub Actions, the CI/CD I use.

I was thinking maybe set up an https localhost within it, or maybe even use the Vercel deployment of that branch.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it after 2 other iterations, and it’s really simple.

Use `local-ssl-proxy` to proxy using ssl, and use that as your Cypress baseUrl.

I can’t believe I thought that it wouldn’t work.